# Mapping two tables with nhibernate to an object

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have a big SQL statement of more than one table and I need to show the data in a table. Now I want to use the old SQL statement to show the data and then I have to understand the whole statement and made a own call.

I want to do like this:

```
using (var session = DbHelper.GetCurrentSession())^
{
    ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT a.ort, b.zeit, b.temperatur from ort a, messwert b where a.id=b.ort_id and ort = 'honolulu' and b.zeit = '1.7.2019'");
    res = query.List();
}
```

I want to map the result to one object.

How can I do this?

```
using (var session = DbHelper.GetCurrentSession())^
{
    ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT a.ort, b.zeit, b.temperatur from ort a, messwert b where a.id=b.ort_id and ort = 'honolulu' and b.zeit = '1.7.2019'");
    res = query.List();
}
```

Comment: @It'satrap NHibernate is an ORM

Comment: How can i to this with NHibernate?